# CQ5 properties.get("foo") String Array.length - JSTL equivalent

Tags: jsp, properties, get, jstl, aem

here is a problem I've been battling with for hours now I will be grateful for any help.

I used scriplets as follows `<%String[] filters = (String[])properties.get("formfactors" ,String[].class) ;%>`
then `<%=filters.length%>`

returns length of filters[] as expected.

now I have to remove all the scriplets from the code

so I did:

```
<cq:defineObjects />

<c:set var="filters" value="${fn:length(properties.filters)}" />

<c:out value="${filters}"/>
```

problem is: this returns the length of the string properties.filters[0] in case that properties.filters.length == 1

like JSTL or CQ was automatically converting the repository variable type from String[] to String

hope this all make sense.

Question is how do I in JSTL force variable type to be String Array or if its CQ returning single string how do I make sure it gets assigned to the array

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A multifield gets stored as a String if there is only one value provided by the author, and as a String Array if the author provides more than one value. This is the default behavior, which cannot be changed unless you override the default multifield.

Hence, we cannot always guarantee an array would be returned for properties.get, due to which we explicitly specify String[].class as the type to which the returned value should be converted to.

But, it is not possible to pass arguments in EL with the servlet version present in CQ (i guess 2.5), though it is possible with EL 2.2 which is part of Servlet 3.0.

One way of achieving this is by using JSP expression for obtaining the value as shown below. This would make sure that your *filters* is always an array, whether it is stored as a String or as a String array.

```
<c:set var="filters" value="<%= properties.get("filters", String[].class) %>" />
<c:out value="${ fn:length(filters) }" />
<c:forEach items="${ filters }" var="filter" >
    <!-- Your logic -->
</c:forEach>
```

In case you have a property object, you can make use of the isMultiple() method to check whether it is multi-valued property or not. For Ex:

```
    <c:if test="${ prop.multiple }" >
        <c:set var="filters" values="${ prop.values }" />
        <!-- Your logic -->
    </c:if>
```

Comment: thanks for your explanations! helps me a lot with a slightly different problem